# Changing IF Else condition values to get from table

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

Instead of hard coding the score and the grades in MS access vba, how can I place the values in a table and access them from a table? This is so that when the score range changes, I do not have to go back to the vba code and update it. I simply update values in the table and code will only pickup score range and allocate the correct grade on the field. Please assist...

```
Private Sub MarkScored_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Dim mScore As Integer

mScore = Nz(Forms![frmAssessmentDetails]![subfrmAcademicAssessment]![MarkScored])

If mScore >= 0 And mScore <= 10 Then
    Forms![frmAssessmentDetails]![subfrmAcademicAssessment]![cboGradeCode] = "VLA"
ElseIf mScore > 10 And mScore <= 15 Then
    Forms![frmAssessmentDetails]![subfrmAcademicAssessment]![cboGradeCode] = "LA"
ElseIf mScore > 15 And mScore <= 20 Then
    Forms![frmAssessmentDetails]![subfrmAcademicAssessment]![cboGradeCode] = "S"
ElseIf mScore > 20 And mScore <= 25 Then
    Forms![frmAssessmentDetails]![subfrmAcademicAssessment]![cboGradeCode] = "HA"
ElseIf mScore > 25 And mScore <= 30 Then
    Forms![frmAssessmentDetails]![subfrmAcademicAssessment]![cboGradeCode] = "VHA"
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter valid mark for Score between 0 and 30", vbOKCancel, "Invalid Number"

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag since this seems to be a VBA Access question.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a new table in database, something like

```
|ID| gradeCode | fromScore | toScore|
 0   VLA         0           10
 1   LA          11          15
 2   S           16          20
```

And then query it in code

```
Select gradeCode from <gradeCodeTableName> where mScore between fromScore and toScore
```

EDIT: As Gustav suggested, the better way to do this without wasting resources is creating table like

```
|ID| gradeCode | fromScore |
 0   VLA         0           
 1   LA          11          
 2   S           16
```

And Query it like

```
Select Top 1 gradeCode From <gradeCodeTableName> Where mScore >= fromScore Order By fromScore Desc
```

You will save 1 column of data

Comment: You only need the _fromScore_ as toScore is redundant: `Select Top 1 gradeCode From <gradeCodeTableName> Where mScore >= fromScore Order By fromScore Desc`

Comment: Well did not think of it this way, thanks for improving my answer! @Gustav

Comment: Thanks Hynek and Gustav..Your answers worked for me..much appreciated..I am a newbie and this is adding to my learning..thank you much for your help..

Comment: @User9123 Please avoid adding updates as answers, it is against the rules :). Anyway when I saw your sql string, you are missing space after WHERE word, so the statement should look like this `"SELECT dbo_AcademicGrade.GradeCode FROM dbo_AcademicGrade WHERE " & mScore & " BETWEEN ScoreRangeFrom AND ScoreRangeTo;"`